# The NSURLSession Task file download occurs after the program needs to use the file

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I have defined an NSURLSession with a download task.  I would like to download a file and then use values in the file in my drawing style kit.  The session and the drawing style kit do run on the synchronous queues, unfortunately the task runs on an NSOperationQueue which does not run until after the view is created.  Therefore, the view does not contain the correct file information.  Is there a coding solution or is it a logic issue and does anyone have suggestions for improving the logic.  I am a newbie so any suggestions are most welcome.

```
class SomeView: UIView, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate

{
var session: NSURLSession!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Create the session configuration
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15.0

    // Create the session
    session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration,
        delegate: self,
        delegateQueue: nil)
}



override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)


        dispatch_sync(queue,
            {
                // Define the data source at www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt
                let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.powerball.com/powerball/winnums-text.txt")

                // Create the download task for the session

                let task = self.session.downloadTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler:
                    {[weak self] (url: NSURL!,
                        response: NSURLResponse!,
                        error: NSError!) in

                        if error == nil
                        {
                            let fileManager = NSFileManager()


                            //Get the path for the caches folder
                            var error: NSError?
                            var cachePath = fileManager.URLForDirectory(
                                NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory,
                                inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask,
                                appropriateForURL: url,
                                create: true,
                                error: &error)!


                            // Assign consistent file name
                            var fileName = "winnums-text"

                            // Apend the file name to the cache path
                            var filePath = cachePath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

                            // Move the file to the file path
                            fileManager.moveItemAtURL(url, toURL: filePath, error: nil)

                            println(filePath)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            println("Connection failed")  //add user notification later
                        }

                        //Clean up sessions
                        self!.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
                })  //Task
                task.resume()
            })  // Dispatch queue

        dispatch_sync(queue,
            {
                    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
                    SomeappStyleKit.drawMain(frame: self.bounds)

            })  // Dispatch queue

}
```

}

Comment: I'll suggest using a 3rd party library. Go ahead and choose your pick at [GitHub](https://github.com).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there are several things ... well ... ill-chosen in my humble opinion I'd say :)

Here is how I would approach that problem.

Your basic idea is:

```
"Have a custom view, that displays stuff according to some information downloaded from the net"
```

First, we should see what we need:

- You need a custom view
- You need some form of asynchronous downloading
- You need some controller that coordinates
- you need to decide, how the whole thing should behave:

  - Is the view only to be created when information is downloaded?
  - Is the view already there in the beginning, and what is it showing meanwhile?
  - What triggers downloading? Some controller? The view really shouldn't.

Now we do **NOT** want to mix any of the asynchronous downloading stuff into the view. The view should only be dumb and display what it is given. (I have to admit I don't know what your view will actually display, so there might be cases where this could be considered valid, but most likely not)

Therefore I'd suggest you create a separate class that handles the downloading and a separate class that is your view.

<s>You could create a `NSOperation` subclass that does all the asynchronous stuff and is enqueued/kicked off by your controller (See [Ray Wenderlich's NSOperation Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) for example) or</s> you can do the asynchronous stuff inside your controller using GCD, and in the completion handler (in either case) tell the view to redisplay itself.

The view could display a placeholder while the content is not downloaded, and by calling a function from the outside (the controller would call this) could re-render itself when new content arrives. One thing is for sure: DrawRect needs to be as fast as possible!

So you might want to have an if statement in there, and only if the content is fetched (the view could have a `Bool` or `Enum` that indicates this state), you call a specialized drawing method of your view, and otherwise just draw the placeholder.

And don't use dispatch_sync anywhere in there... in fact, don't use it anywhere at all. You really want to be *asynchronous* in most cases (as usual, exceptions apply). In this special case inside `drawRect` you really MUST not use any GCD functions like this, as drawRect is called on the main thread afaik and you must not do any drawing outside the main thread.

I hope this gets you started. Otherwise I might find the time to come up with some code later this week.

**Edit:** You could just use the NSURLDownloadTask you have, but in a controller. A separate NSOperation subclass might not be the best option here and unnecessary.

Comment: @Krajacic, Thank you so much.  Moved the task to the view controller.  Took out the GCD, the app performed well without it.  Modified the style kit to display placeholders.  I am working now on getting the View Controller to refresh the UIView after the file is downloaded.  Your comments were very helpful.  Sent me on the correct path.